# ReactQuery with ContextAPI

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-query

I'm programming using React and recently I learned ReactQuery and I have few thoughts, questions and wonderings:
(All the things I'm gonna say is accourding to a specific data like always data means books for instance)

1).when would I choose to fetch the data through ReactQuery everywhere I'm fetching this data or creating a data ContextAPI for it?

2).If I decide to use ContextAPI how would I implement it using ReactQuery? In addition how to decide the staletime without re-fetching too much?
Accourding to the first part of number 2 - Like I fetch the data from the ReactQuery and wanna give it to the context values how do i do that?

3).If I'm re-fetching in the Context but the data remain the same will it re-render?
If it does re-render can I preventing it using memoization?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to implement any sort of additional context layer over top of React Query. That is one of the key values of RQ -- it handles all of this for you, and is *really* good at it! So, to answer your questions:

1. You should fetch your data through React Query everywhere. Any component that needs to fetch data should do so through a React Query hook. RQ will cache query responses, so multiple components can implement the same query, but only one request will go out. Additionally, you can configure specific queries to have different stale times, in case you have some data that will need to be frequently re-fetched or never re-fetched.
2. RQ gives you the ability to configure how many retries it should attempt before failing, as well as the stale time.
3. Generally speaking, you should only be re-fetching data when you expect it to be changed. This can be accomplished with `QueryClient.invalidateQueries(["myQueryKey])` to force a refetch. In cases where you're extremely worried about unnecessary re-renders, I'm *pretty* sure RQ will not trigger a refresh if the newly fetched data is identical to the existing data. But, I'm not 100% sure on that point.

Comment: Ok thank you so much.about 1- I tried to get access to the cache data in other place that before I tried doing that it was inactive accourding to the devtools.does it mean the data will re-fetch after the stale time?moreover can you explain more about what you said after ''additionally''? about 2 how can I make different staletimes and how implementing the fetching accourding to that?

Comment: If a query is stale, that doesn't mean it will automatically re-fetch -- there are several conditions under which it will re-fetch, detailed in the docs: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/important-defaults

Different stale times and re-fetch attempts are available as fields on the useQuery options parameter. (ex: useQuery(["myQuery"], { queryFn: () => {}, staleTime: 5000})

Comment: ohh ok. And if I'm not refering any other stale time it will be the stale time I initially decide and if I am it will override the initial one right?